# Унаследовать класс

Tags: android, kotlin

Как я могу унаследовать класс DatabaseTestCase

1) объекту

```
object ProfilesRepository : BaseSyncRepository<Profile, ProfileData>()
```

2) презентеру

```
class Presenter(val contract: UnlockAppViewContract?)
```

Пробовал по схеме, но увы так не работает

```
class : DatabaseTestCase
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Никак, множественное наследование в Java (и соответственно в Kotlin) не поддерживается. Класс может реализовать (implements в Java) несколько интерфейсов, но наследовать (extends в Java) может только один класс. А в вашем случае класс `ProfilesRepository` уже наследует от класса `BaseSyncRepository`

2)

```
class Presenter(val contract: UnlockAppViewContract?) : DatabaseTestCase()
```

Вы забыли `()` которые заменяют в Kotlin инициализацию родительского класса (вызов `super()` в Java)

Здесь можно подробней прочитать про наследование: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance